# Should I keep counters in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 collections: Tracks and Users

Simplified:

```
trackSchema = new mongoose.Schema
    title: String
    artist: String
    userId: String
    playlists: [String]

userSchema = new mongoose.Schema
    username: String
    trackCount: Integer
    playlists: {}
```

So user.playlists keeps track of the number of tracks in each playlist and trackCount keeps track of the total number of tracks for a user

Say user1 have 2 tracks, track1, and track2. Both belong to 1 playlist called myplaylist, I would have

```
track1.playlists = ["myplaylist"]
track2.playlists = ["myplaylist"]
user1.playlists = { myplaylist: 2 }
user1.trackCount = 2
```

Is it a good to keep track of the counters this way? I find that it complicates the implementation but I make sure Mongo is not querying the counts every time I need them, do that makes sense?

Comment: It depends on how you are going to store playlists and tracks.  Will each user have an array of playlists and then each playlist has an array of tracks?  If so, don't store counts at the user level.  Instead just grab the whole object and you can check the length of the arrays.

Comment: tracks is a collection, but playlist is denormalized, and it's stored in tracks and in users. Edited the question to give more info

Comment: If it's something your app needs and frequently uses, seems worth maintaining.